# Laravel: сервис-контейнеры и сервис-провайдеры. Что это и зачем?

Tags: php, laravel

Недавно перешел с фреймворка CodeIgniter (в котором была простая схема MVC) на изучение Laravel. Фреймворк очень понравился, но есть некоторые моменты, которые я никак не могу понять, сколько бы не читал документацию. В частности что такое сервис-контейнеры и сервис-провайдеры и зачем они нужны. Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: все когда-то грешили на игнайтере, но из-за его поддержки он стал слабеньким, но плюсы все равно остались у него)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ну что-ж, попробую объяснить. С Богом!

Все возможности я не опишу, просто **попытаюсь** дать представление и возможно (скорее всего) не совсем точно.

---

**Введение:**

Вообще эти штуки нужны, в первую очередь, для удобства, как плюс — они реализуют паттерн **Dependency Injection**. С него и начнём.

---

```
class myClassA {
    private $obj;
    function __construct() {
        $this->obj =  new myClassB;
    }
}
```

Красиво?... Нет! Почему? А в друг нам понадобится, чтобы при создании класс `myClassB` принимал аргументы в свой конструктор? Придётся переписывать. Вы скажете: "*перепишу, ничего страшного*", но если таких классов `myClassA` много, то тут уже косяк — надо разруливать, для этого и придумали паттерн, глянем на то, как надо:

```
function __construct(myClassB $classB) {
     $this->obj =  $classB;
}
```

Т.е. мы в конструктор передали уже существующий класс `myClassB`, но где мы его создали? ведь `new` нигде не писали. Магия? Можно представить, что мы в Хогвартсе и зачитать заклинание `"PHP Reflection"` (но это уже отдельная тема). Так а `Laravel` что?

Сложно описать, давайте покажем, переведем наш класс `myClassA` в контроллер:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

use App\MyClass\MyClassB;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $obj;
    public function __construct(MyClassB $classB) {
        $this->obj = $classB;
    }
    public function index() {
        echo $this->obj->myMethod();
    }
}
```

Но нужно теперь и `MyClassB` создать. Сразу вспомним начало, нам нужно учитывать что класс должен что-то принимать. Создаем папочку `app\MyClass` и там файлик `MyClassB.php` с текстом:

```
<?php
namespace App\MyСlass;
class MyClassB
{
    private $action;
    public function __construct($action) {
        $this->action = $action;
    }
    public function myMethod() {
        return "Laravel - ".$this->action;
    }
}
```

Ну что? Запускаем? Не-не... надо ж как-то передать какой нибудь `$action` в конструктор. Плюс, вот тут уже справедливо сказать, что `Laravel` не понимает, что у нас с зависимостями (*ведь класс* `myClassA` *зависит от* `myClassB`). А мы только тупо создали файл и в нём класс, надо что-то ещё. Вот тут НАКОНЕЦ-ТАКИ мы переходим к `Сервис-провайдеру`, просим всемогущего `Artisan` создать нам новый провайдер:

```
php artisan make:provider MyProvider
```

Далее, во вторую вкладочку открываем документацию и заполняем его (а сам файлик должен быть тут - `app\Providers`):

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\MyClass\MyClassB;

class MyProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {}
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(MyClassB::class, function(){
            return new MyClassB('MyAction');
        });
    }
}
```

Из документации видно, что внутри метода `register()` как раз и должны быть наши связывания, простенькие примеры:

```
// Если хотим, чтобы каждый вызов, возвращался новый класс
$this->app->bind(MyClassB::class, function(){
    return new MyClassB('MyAction');
});
// Если хотим, чтобы был создан только один объект и всегда он возвращался
$this->app->singleton(MyClassB::class, function(){
    return new MyClassB('MyAction');
});
```

Стоит также одним глазком глянуть в документацию на строчку:

> Если вы откроете файл config/app.php, поставляемый с Laravel, то
>   увидите массив providers. В нём перечислены все классы
>   сервис-провайдеров, которые загружаются для вашего приложения.

Наш `MyProvider` тоже должен быть в этом списке.

Теперь можно запускать и, в принципе, всё должно работать. Теперь мы знаем, что `MyProvider` - это и есть `Сервис-провайдер` (внимательные заметили, что расширяет наш класс именно `ServiceProvider`. Совпадение?). Грубо говоря, это инструкция, которая создаст нам класс, чтобы другие классы могли им пользоваться (и в других местах).

Вроде разобрались с `Сервис-провайдерами`. Абасаца... А теперь еще `Сервис-контейнер`.

Продолжаем стори... Так а где был создан `MyClassB`? Так вот, можно сказать, что он был создан в `Сервис-контейнере`. Srsly?

Можно сказать что `Сервис-контейнер` — это массив (*array(key => value)*), где ключ `MyClassB::class`, а значение это `new MyClassB('MyAction')`, и запись мы произвели с помощью метода `bind`. Но, на самом деле, помимо условного массива — это целый механизм, который позволяет делать такую магию в целом, вспоминаем наше заклинание из Хогвартса и зовется сие - `Сервисом`.

Дочитали до конца? Бонусы:

1) Когда мы в `app.php` прописали провайдер, он будет автоматически создан и занесён в контейнер, а если он не так часто используется, зачем его каждый раз создавать? Для этого воспользуемся термином `Отложенный-провайдер`, для этого в нашем провайдере (*мы-же теперь знаем, что это*), нужно прописать `protected $defer = true;` тогда он будет создан только по запросу.

2) Мы можем и в коде обращаться к нашему контейнеру, например `$getClass = $this->app->make('MyClassB');` (либо `resolve('MyClassB');`) (подробнее в документации)

*P.S. В конце хочу добавить, что критику принимаю :) Подправим, допилим, может в будущем кому пригодится.*

Comment: То есть laravel смотрит что в методе контроллера параметр это объект класса MyClassB, ищет в контейнере связь для класса MyClassB и дает ее в соответствующий параметр метода контроллера который сам laravel и вызывает(действие роута, например, в случае для Вашего примера в ответе -  для конструктора). Правильно понял? А провайдеры это классы которые могут работать с сервис контейнером(не обязательно только для этого), они просто группируют код.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Частично. но не совсем так.

Comment: Фраза "ведь класс myClassA зависит от myClassB" на самом деле должна звучать как  "ведь класс MyController зависит от myClassB", я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

В кратце

Сервис-контейнер - инструмент для управления зависимостями классов и внедрения зависимостей.

Сервис-провайдеры - центральное место для конфигурирования.

Вот пару постов:

https://webzone.kz/publication/laravel-service-container

https://webzone.kz/publication/laravel-service-providers