# Вызвать метод сервиса через интерфейс Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Помогите разобраться со следующей задачей.

Есть контроллер `PaymentController`:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller implements \App\Services\Payment
{
    public function pay(Payment $obj)
    {
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus(Payment $obj)
    {
    }
}
```

В нём два метода `pay` и `getPaymentStatus`. У них в параметрах есть объект интерфейса.

Вот интерфейс `Payment`:

```
interface Payment
{
    public function pay();

    public function getPaymentStatus();
}
```

И есть два сервиса `PayPal` и `PrivatBank`, которые реализуют этот интерфейс:

```
    class PayPal implements Payment
    {
        public function pay()
        {
           //Реализация
        }

       public function getPaymentStatus()
        {
           //Реализация
        }
    }



    class PrivatBank implements Payment
    {
        public function pay()
        {
           //Реализация
        }

       public function getPaymentStatus()
        {
           //Реализация
        }
    }
```

Как в контроллере, в методе `pay()` вызвать реализацию метода `pay()` из сервиса `PayPal` или `PrivatBank`?

У меня есть только вариант - передавать в маршруте ещё и название класса и создавать объект этого класса в методе контроллера.

Comment: Возможно для вас это будет не в тему и вы об этом знаете, но тем не менее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850398/256824

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера прочитал в интернете несколько статей про провайдеры, но всё равно не понял как реализовать мой вариант.

Но я прочту то, что вы скинули и если пойму и реализую, тогда закрою вопрос.

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы вы разобрались и сами дали ответ. Добавив метку PHP, можно расширить аудиторию. Сам я не сталкивался с динамической регистрацией сервисов. А, возможно, было бы лучше поискать на гите, наверняка есть готовые пакеты.

Comment: Конечно, если разберусь, тогда отвечу на вопрос.

Всё таки, я думаю это распространённая практика, так как это подразумевает принцип SOLID (Dependency invertion)

Comment: Прочитал ответ, который вы прикрепи, но это немного не то.

Comment: Что-то не кто не отвечает, разве не сталкивались с такой задачей?

Или может быть как-то по-другому нужно решить, подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из примеров, хоть и не самых показательных. Откликается на маршруты типа:

```
Route::post('/player', 'PlayerController@upload')->name('player.upload');
Route::get('/player', 'PlayerController@download')->name('player.download');
```

Ну и данные не обязательно могут быть получены из *Request* - это может быть сессия, куки и так далее. Можете еще какую-нибудь "прокладку" воткнуть, которая будет этим управлять. В примере намерено использован отвлеченный *Player*, вместо *Payment*, так как существуют готовые пакеты приема оплаты.

```
/**
 * config\app.php
 */
'providers' => [
  ...
  App\Providers\PlayerServiceProvider::class,
];


/**
 * app\Providers\PlayerServiceProvider.php
 */
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Player\AudioPlayer;
use App\Services\Player\VideoPlayer;
use App\Services\Contracts\PlayerServiceInterface;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PlayerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $defer = true;

  /**
   * Register services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
    $this->registerPlayerService();
  }

  protected function registerPlayerService()
  {
    $player = $this->app->make('request')->get('player');

    $this->app->singleton(PlayerServiceInterface::class, function ($app) use ($player) {
      if ('video' === $player) {
        return new VideoPlayer();
      }

      return new AudioPlayer();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get the services provided by the provider.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function provides()
  {
    return [PlayerServiceInterface::class];
  }
}


/**
 * app\Http\Controllers\PlayerController.php
 */
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Services\Contracts\PlayerServiceInterface;

class PlayerController extends Controller
{
  protected $player;

  public function __construct(PlayerServiceInterface $player)
  {
    $this->player = $player;
  }

  public function upload(Request $request)
  {
    dd($this->player->upload());
  }

  public function download(Request $request)
  {
    dd($this->player->download());
  }
}


/**
 * app\Services\Contracts\PlayerServiceInterface.php
 */
namespace App\Services\Contracts;

Interface PlayerServiceInterface
{
  public function upload();

  public function download();
}


/**
 * app\Services\Player\AudioPlayer.php
 */
namespace App\Services\Player;

use App\Services\Contracts\PlayerServiceInterface;

class AudioPlayer implements PlayerServiceInterface
{
  public function upload()
  {
    return 'Реализация метода upload() сервиса AudioPlayer.';
  }

  public function download()
  {
    return 'Реализация метода download() сервиса AudioPlayer.';
  }
}


/**
 * app\Services\Player\VideoPlayer.php
 */
namespace App\Services\Player;

use App\Services\Contracts\PlayerServiceInterface;

class VideoPlayer implements PlayerServiceInterface
{
  public function upload()
  {
    return 'Реализация метода upload() сервиса VideoPlayer.';
  }

  public function download()
  {
    return 'Реализация метода download() сервиса VideoPlayer.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, уже не первый раз выручаешь)

Буду реализовывать)

Comment: Что ты имеешь ввиду? Сама реализация оплаты у меня не кастомная, а с документации, как нужно. Мой вопрос был в расширяемости приложения.

Comment: не подскажешь почему не заходит в if вот здесь? Пропускает  $this->app->singleton(PlayerServiceInterface::class, function ($app) use ($player) {
      if ('video' === $player) {
        return new VideoPlayer();
      }

      return new AudioPlayer();
    });

Comment: Через xDebug проверяю, просто пропускает данный блок

Comment: Передайтся, в player = 'video'