# Для чего нужны services provider в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Объясните, пожалуйста, более простым языком для чего нужны в laravel services provider

Вот к примеру у меня есть свой сервис в проекте, он зависим от других репозиториев и утилит классов, я их обычно вызываю таким методом

```
public function __construct(
    protected readonly object $userMetaRepository = new UserMetaRepository(),
    protected readonly object $userRepository = new userRepository()
)
{}
```

А после в коде обращаюсь и вызываю уже методы класса которые мне нужны. Хочу вашего мнения насколько это вообще правильно, какие есть минусы у данного подхода и насколько ограничивает скорости работы бэкенда в целом?

Лазая по просторам интернета увидел что можно воспользоваться и создать свой services provider для своих репозиториев и примеры их использования выглядит вот так

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(DemoOne $customServiceInstance)
    {
       echo $customServiceInstance->doSomethingUseful();
    }
}
```

Но до меня не как не доходит их преимущество и смысл

Comment: А что если вам нужен объект в конструкторе которого 5 аргументов. И нужен он, скажем, во всех контроллерах. Как вы тогда поступите?

Comment: @ArchDemon собственно в этом и состоит часть вопроса. Что у меня в методе не идут вызовы сервисов, все сервисы и прочие у меня вызываются в конструкторе контролера, а после используются где нужно. Я просто запутался, узнав о существовании services provider и начал узнавать как им пользоваться и просто встал в тупик не понимая что правильнее. Так же имеет ли смысл добавлять в сервис провайдер привязку "$this->app->bind(UserSubscriptionServicesInterfaces::class, UserSubscriptionServices::class)"

Comment: Laravel позволяет авто-DI, т.е. можно просто у метода указывать нужные сервисы `public function index(userRepository $userRepository, UserMetaRepository $userMetaRepository) {...`, зачастую в конструкторе много методов и единицы используют сервисы добавленные в конструкторе, поэтому этот паттерн не лучший вариант.

Comment: А касательно сервис провайдеров, это гибкий инструмент управления/настройки. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/850407/330342 (там много чего добавить можно, но вы это откроете по мере роста, нет смысла сейчас это объяснять)

Comment: @InDevX я понял, спасибо вам большое за дополнительную информацию